# Assign and increment value on one line

Tags: python

Is it possible to assign a value and increment the assigned value on the same line in Python?

Something like this:

```
x = 1
a = x
b = (x += 1)
c = (x += 1)

print a
print b
print c

>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
```

I need it in a context where I'm creating an Excel sheet:

```
col = row = 1
ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = "A cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=(col += 1)).value = "Another cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=(col += 1)).value = "Another cell value"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No that’s not possible in **Python versions < 3.8**.

[Assignments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) (or [augmented assignments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)) are statements and as such may not appear on the right-hand side of another assignment. You can only assign *expressions* to variables.

The reason for this is most likely to avoid confusions from side effects which are easily caused in other languages that support this.

However, normal assignments do support multiple targets, so you can assign the same expression to multiple variables. This of course still only allows you to have a single expression on the right-hand side (still no statement). In your case, since you want `b` and `x` to end up with the same value, you could write it like this:

```
b = x = x + 1
c = x = x + 1
```

Note that since you’re doing `x = x + 1` you are no longer using an augmented assignment and as such could have different effects for some types (not for integers though).

Answer (score 6):

[Since Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-8), you can use the [walrus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walrus#/media/File:Pacific_Walrus_-_Bull_(8247646168).jpg) which was introduced in [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). This operator creates an [assignment ***expression***](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions). So you can assign new values to variables, ***while returning the newly assigned value***:

```py
>>> print(f"{(x := 1)}")
1
>>> x
1
>>> print(f"{(x := x+1)}")
2
>>> x
2
>>> b = (x := x+1)
>>> b, x
(3, 3)
```

---

In the context of your question, this will work:

```
col = row = 1
ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = "A cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=(col := col+1)).value = "Another cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=(col := col+1)).value = "Another cell value"
```

Comment: **The only sane answer.** The accepted answer even acknowledges that Python ≥ 3.8 supports this... then fails to actually document *how.* `</double_facepalm>`

Comment: @CecilCurry To be fair, I added that comment in the other answer because when I posted mine that answer simply said *"no, that's not possible"* which is just wrong. I just wanted to make it clear for future readers

Answer (score 4):

Not a pretty one but you can do something like this.

```
x = 1
a = x
x = b = x+1
x = c = x+1

>>> print a,b,c 
>>> 1,2,3

>>>print id(a),id(b),id(c),id(x)
>>>31098952 31098928 31098904 31098904
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a function,here I use the lambda function. There is no exact python equivalent of `++x` or `x++` in c.

```
inc =lambda t: t+1
x = 1
a = x
b,x=inc(x),x+1
c,x = inc(x),x+1

print a
print b
print c
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want a function there. The code is equivalent to `b, x = x + 1, x + 1`

Comment: @poke True indeed. I wrote the first thing I thought of.Well the function can be used for some other complex operation if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range`, `iter` and `next`:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

col = row = 1
iter_int = iter(range(col, col + 100))

ws.cell(row=row, column=next(iter_int)).value = "A cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=next(iter_int)).value = "Another cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=next(iter_int)).value = "Another cell value"

wb.save("cell_values.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>* self-answer by the OP that was edited into the question:</sup>

---

It's not possible, but I have created an easy fix:

```
col = row = 1

def increment_one():
    global col
    col += 1
    return col

ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = "A cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=increment_one()).value = "Another cell value"
ws.cell(row=row, column=increment_one()).value = "Another cell value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment within an if statement returning when a boundary is being exceeded. I found this idiom to be simple and clean when a state machine required dozens of increment and tests.

```
if (i := i+1) >= limit: return i
```